# Disabling jQuery ComboBox on page initialisation. Re-Enabling [StreetName] Combobox depending on the value of [Postcode] Combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, disable

I am trying to have 4 ComboBoxes on my webpage.

When the page loads [Initialisation] only one [Postcode] combobox has to be enabled and rest all [StreetName, Suburb, State] have to be disabled.

Now when I select a valid value from the autocomplete dropdown of the Postcode combobox element, I want only the [Streetname] combobox to get enabled.

Similarly when I select a valid value from the autocomplete dropdown of the StreetName combobox element, I want only the [Suburb] combobox to get enabled. Similarly would be the case for [State] combobox.

I have till now tweaked the already available code for AutoComplete ComboBox on jQuery website (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

I am also pasting the code down below for my combobox.js file as well as my cshtml file.

---

**combobox.js**

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        options: {
            source: function (request, response) { console.error('source not defined') },
            select: function (event, ui) { },
            change: function (event, ui) { },
            showTitleForAllItems: true,
            showAllTitleText: 'Show All Items'
        },
        _cache: [],
        _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
              .addClass("custom-combobox")
              .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function () {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

               this.input = $("<input>")
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .val(value)
              .attr("title", "")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
              .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 0,
                  source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
              })
              .tooltip({
                  classes: {
                      "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                  }
              });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                    //ui.item.value.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.value
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function () {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;

            $("<a>")
              .attr("tabIndex", -1)
              .attr("title", "Show All Items")
              .tooltip()
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                  icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                  },
                  text: false
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
              .on("mousedown", function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })
              .on("click", function () {
                  input.trigger("focus");

                  // Close if already visible
                  if (wasOpen) {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                  input.autocomplete("search", "");
              });
        },

        _source: function (request, response) {
            var that = this;
            var data = this.options.source(request, function (data) {

                that._cache = that._cache.concat(data);
                response(data)
            });

        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item)
            {
                this.options.change(event, ui);
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this._cache.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid)
            {
                //this.options.change(event, ui);
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
              .val("")
              .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
              .tooltip("open");
            this.element.val("");
            this._delay(function () {
                this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
            }, 2500);
            this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
});

});
```

---

**cshtml**

```
<div class="shipping-information-block-right">
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-right">
                Postcode:<br>
                <input type="text" id="Postcode" name="Postcode">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-left">
                @*<label>Street Name<span class="red-star">*</span></label>*@
            </div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-right">
                Street Name:<br>
                <input type="text" id="StreetName" name="StreetName">
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-left">
                @*<label>Suburb<span class="red-star">*</span></label>*@
            </div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-right">
                Suburb<br>
                <input type="text" id="Suburb" name="Suburb">
                <br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-left">
                @*<label>State<span class="red-star">*</span></label>*@
            </div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-cehckout-form-left-inner-right">
                State:<br>
                <input type="text" id="State" name="State">
                <br><br>
            </div>

        </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StreetName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#Suburb').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#State').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $('#Postcode').combobox({
            source: function (request, response) {
                debugger;
                var data = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/en/B2B/Menu/Online-Shop/Online-Payment/Shipping/GetAddressDetails",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        PostCode: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$.each(data.Entity, function(index, value) {
                        //    temporary[i++] = value.PostCode;
                        //})
                        //dbData = jQuery.unique(temporary);
                        var data = $.map(data.Entity, function (item) {
                            return item.PostCode;
                        });
                        response(data);
                        debugger;
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                });

            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item == null) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#StreetName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else
                {
                    debugger;
                    $(function () {
                        $('#StreetName').removeAttr("disabled");
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        if ($('#StreetName').attr("disabled", "disabled")) {
            debugger;
            $("#StreetName").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#StreetName').combobox({
                disabled: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = [];
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/en/B2B/Menu/Online-Shop/Online-Payment/Shipping/GetAddressDetails",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            StreetName: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //$.each(data.Entity, function(index, value) {
                            //    temporary[i++] = value.PostCode;
                            //})
                            //dbData = jQuery.unique(temporary);
                            var data = $.map(data.Entity, function (item) {
                                return item.StreetName;
                            });
                            response(data);
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }

        if ($('#Suburb').attr("disabled", "disabled")) {
            debugger;
            $("#Suburb").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#Suburb').combobox({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = [];
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/en/B2B/Menu/Online-Shop/Online-Payment/Shipping/GetAddressDetails",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            Suburb: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //$.each(data.Entity, function(index, value) {
                            //    temporary[i++] = value.PostCode;
                            //})
                            //dbData = jQuery.unique(temporary);
                            var data = $.map(data.Entity, function (item) {
                                return item.Suburb;
                            });
                            response(data);
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
        if ($('#State').attr("disabled", "disabled")) {
            debugger;
            $("#State").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true).prop("disabled", true);
            $("#State").parent().find("a.ui-button").button("disable");
        }
        else {
            $('#State').combobox({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = [];
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/en/B2B/Menu/Online-Shop/Online-Payment/Shipping/GetAddressDetails",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            State: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //$.each(data.Entity, function(index, value) {
                            //    temporary[i++] = value.PostCode;
                            //})
                            //dbData = jQuery.unique(temporary);
                            var data = $.map(data.Entity, function (item) {
                                return item.State;
                            });
                            response(data);
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am hereby mentioning the changes that I did in my code in both the files to make the functionality as was expected. I hope this helps someone who might be looking for the same sort of functionality.

**cshtml file**

All the comboboxes are like this, except the Postcode combobox. In Postcode Combobox enabled is set to true, as that is required when the page loads.

```
$('#StreetName').combobox({
            enabled: false,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = [];
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/en/B2B/Menu/Online-Shop/Online-Payment/Shipping/GetAddressDetails",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            StreetName: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //$.each(data.Entity, function(index, value) {
                            //    temporary[i++] = value.PostCode;
                            //})
                            //dbData = jQuery.unique(temporary);
                            var data = $.map(data.Entity, function (item) {
                                return item.StreetName;
                            });
                            response(data);
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                },
                change: function (event, ui) {

                    if (ui.item == null) {
                        debugger;
                        $("#Suburb").combobox("toggleState", false);
                    }
                    else {
                        debugger;
                        $("#Suburb").combobox("toggleState", true);
                    }
                },
                change: function (valid) {
                    if (valid) {
                        $("#Suburb").combobox("toggleState", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#Suburb").combobox("toggleState", false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

In the combobox.js library file, I have modified the options as well as the create function and also the section where it handles the invalid value, Kindly see for your reference.

**combobox.js**

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        options: {
            source: function (request, response) { console.error('source not defined') },
            select: function (event, ui) { },
            change: function (event, ui) { },
            change: function (valid) { },
            enabled: true, 
            showTitleForAllItems: true,
            showAllTitleText: 'Show All Items',
        },
        toggleState: function (state) {
            if(state)
            {
                this.input.prop('disabled', false);
                this.input.autocomplete("enable");
                this.a.prop("enable");
            }
            else
            {
                this.input.prop('disabled', true);
                this.input.autocomplete("disable");
                this.a.prop("disable");
            }
        },
        _cache: [],
        _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
              .addClass("custom-combobox")
              .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
            this._enabled();
        },

        _enabled: function ()
        {
            if (this.options.enabled)
            {
                this.toggleState(true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.toggleState(false);
            }
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function () {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

               this.input = $("<input>")
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .val(value)
              .attr("title", "")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
              .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 0,
                  source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
              })
              .tooltip({
                  classes: {
                      "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
                  }
              });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                    //ui.item.value.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.value
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function () {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;
            this.a = $("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1);
            if (this.options.showTitleForAllItems) {
                btn = $(this.a)
                .attr("title", this.options.showAllTitleText)
              .tooltip()
            }
            $(this.a)
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                  icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                  },
                  text: false
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
              .on("mousedown", function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })
              .on("click", function () {
                  input.trigger("focus");

                  // Close if already visible
                  if (wasOpen) {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                  input.autocomplete("search", "");
              });
        },

        _source: function (request, response) {
            var that = this;
            var data = this.options.source(request, function (data) {

                that._cache = that._cache.concat(data);
                response(data)
            });

        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item)
            {
                this.options.change(event, ui);
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this._cache.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid)
            {
                this.options.change(valid);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.options.change(valid);
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
              .val("")
              .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
              .tooltip("open");
            this.element.val("");
            this._delay(function () {
                this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
            }, 2500);
            this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });

});
```